# calling a managed c++ dll function from c#

Tags: c#, c++

Here is my c# main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i;
        unsafe
        {
        hdf_call_vars_t ret_vals;

        //IntPtr a ;
        //Marshal.PtrToStructure(a,ret_vals);

        ret_vals.fetch_nav = 1;
        string str = "C:\\DoAT\\a.h5";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);

            fixed (byte* p = bytes)
            {
                sbyte* sp = (sbyte*)p;
                //SP is now what you want
                DoAT.atrClass1 cl = new DoAT.atrClass1();

                cl.read_hdf5_file(sp,  ret_vals);
```

where the struct in c# is

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
/* Returned values from read_hdf5_file */
unsafe struct hdf_call_vars_t {
    public channel_vars p_vars; 
    public channel_vars s_vars; 
    FILE_VERSION file_vers; /* Set in top level sub. used in lower */
    public int fetch_nav; /* Boolean flag */
    public s_line_header_t * n_addr; /* malloc'd address of n data */
    public UInt32 n_lines;
    csdt_file_header_t hdr; 
};
```

this does not compile, says 'cl' needs as input a pointer to the hdf_call_vars_t.

In my c++ managed dll I have

```
int atrClass1::read_hdf5_file
    (const char * file_path, /* Path to  file */
     hdf_call_vars_t & ret_vals)
```

and also

```
struct hdf_call_vars {
    struct channel_vars p_vars; 
    struct channel_vars s_vars; 
    enum FILE_VERSION file_vers; /* Set in top level sub. used in lower */
    int fetch_n;     
    s_line_header_t * n_addr; /* malloc'd address of  data */
    unsigned int n_lines;
    csdt_file_header_t hdr; 
};
typedef struct hdf_call_vars hdf_call_vars_t;
```

Why does c# think a pointer needs to be sent into C++? If it is so, how do I make a pointer of the struct in the c# world?

Comment: See IntPtr http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr(v=VS.100).aspx#Y69

Comment: Your C++ code says &ret_vals, which means you have to pass your struct by reference

Comment: thank you, Allen and jszigeti. I did try

Comment: cl.read_hdf5_file(sp,  ref ret_vals); but got the same compile error.

Comment: I'm not a pinvoke expert myself, but Allen is saying you need to pass ret_vals as an IntPtr. You can experiment with this by just passing an arbitrary IntPtr, and seeing if your code _at least_ compiles. Then figure out how to set ret_vals to be an IntPtr.

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ DLL is managed, why don't you just mark atrClass1 as managed and avoid all the P/Invoke mess?

```
public ref class atrClass1
{
public:
    int read_hdf5_file(String^ file_path, hdf_call_vars^% ret_vals)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Then you can use that directly from C#.

Of couse you also need a managed version of hdf_call_vars. You should also make the code more object-oriented (avoid POD types like the current hdf_call_vars).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not familiar with managed code and have no confidence in trying to wing it. I think I'll have to try the intptr route which also I'm unfamiliar with. thanks for helping.